# Does the delete/undelete vote feature need to be revisited?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

Compared to Downvote, Close-vote, and Reopen-vote, the Delete-vote and Undelete-vote lack some significant features

1. For a question/answer, the Downvote, Close-vote, and Reopen-vote can be cast only once by a user while the Delete-vote can be cast as many times as a user wants. This opens the door to misuse, e.g. coordinated Delete-vote, which may be followed by coordinated Undelete-vote, and the Delete/Undelete voting may go in an unending cycle.
2. The Downvote costs `1` point to the voter, and undoubtedly it's a great feature. Having this feature with Delete-vote can prove a deterrent to the misuse of Delete-vote. For the Delete-vote, the deduction can be made even bigger e.g. `5` points.
3. The Delete-vote cannot be retracted: Currently, there is no way to retract the Delete-vote if it was cast accidentally.
4. Nice to have: The Close-vote requires a reason to be mentioned which helps the contributors to edit the question. The Delete-vote lacks this feature.
5. Not sure: I am not sure if a Delete/Undelete vote expires. If it doesn't, it can be useful to introduce this feature to it.

These are my thoughts on this subject, but I'm looking for more thoughts and suggestions as well.

Comment: deletion is already locked behind a very high rep requirement and is limited to questions that have already been significantly downvoted or closed.

Comment: whoops, "*and* closed", not or. it must be closed, and if it's significantly downvoted, 20k'ers can delete it early rather than needing to wait 2 days after closure. it's hardly something people can just freely throw around, and not something you can generally "accidentally" do.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to add a retracting feature to delete votes. Reopen votes should also have this option.

Comment: Regarding point one: [Why is it possible to vote for deletion/undeletion more than once?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431) ... so do you say you witnessed misuse of the delete vote?

Comment: The argument for reducing points is quite strange. You want to deter misuse of the delete vote, ok, but don't care about the misuse of undelete votes? Misuse of reopen votes or misuse of the upvote? Why shouldn't we retract 5 points there as well?

Comment: I'm upvoting this post because it's tagged [discussion], not [feature-request], and because I agree with half of it.  I would suggest to others that it raises enough valid points as to be worth not burying off the front page. It asks a question that's worth discussing, even if one disagrees with some of the proposals.

Comment: Also, to the close voters: what exactly do you find unclear about this?  It seems quite clear to me.  I hope that close votes aren't being used to express that this is a bad idea.

Comment: Personally, I agree with #1 and #3 (single actioned delete/undelete vote per post and retractable delete and reopen votes), I strongly disagree with #2 (while we want people to use delete-votes responsibly, the solution isn't to penalize them for using the privilege) & #4 (close-votes require a reason, because we're *really* wanting OPs to improve their post for reopening, whereas delete-votes are removing content which is detrimental to the site for it to be retained). Overall, this got a downvote from me, because I'd rather see the current status quo, than to have this fully implemented.

Comment: "The Downvote cost 1 point to the voter, and undoubtedly it's a great feature" — Really? Undoubtedly great? I can see why it might be seen as a necessary evil (maybe), but I think it's really unfortunate that the site mechanics give the impression to people they are bad for downvoting, when there's lots of stuff that should be downvoted. And deleted.

Comment: #2 is terrible and should never be considered

Comment: @RyanM perhaps the fact it's not actually asking anything, it's tagged as support, why? What support do they need? They seem to understand how the system works even if they don't like it. It's tagged as discussion without any prompts for discussion, they've given a list of problems they have yet not asked what people think of them, why they are the way they are, for any other ways to improve it, etc. It could potentially be a FR, but they seem to think there's problems missing from their list without giving any reasoning which doesnt work for a FR. It's just a rant, what do they actually want?

Comment: Adding to what @Nick said, it's one of many such requests/posts/rants from someone who has taken strong issues with the way site moderation is working. But why? Is it out of concern for how moderation affects site question and answer quality? or is it out of concern for how moderation affects an individual contributor's reputation?

Comment: I would've kept going, but hard to do multi-comment comments on a phone and I had to start taking out punctuation to even fit all the words in that I managed to...

Comment: @Ole It’s funny that users often complain about downvotes without comments, yet this thread is filled with direct feedback and yet you still have no clue why there might be downvotes.

Comment: @Makyen - *I strongly disagree with #2 (while we want people to use delete-votes responsibly, the solution isn't to penalize them for using the privilege* - What is the point of penalizing the downvoters then?

Comment: @khelwood - If costing 1 point is justified for the Downvote, how is it unjustified for Delete-vote?

Comment: @yivi I have clues. I just prefer hearing from downvoters themselves rather than guessing. It’s probably just me being unfamiliar with meta, so please allow me to ask. I am not complaining, I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Makyen The tooltip for the downvote button says *This question does not show any research effort:; it is unclear or not useful.* Should that be changed to *I am opposed to what this question suggests.*? Still trying to understand the reason/s for the downvotes. IMHO this question started a fruitful exchange of opinions, so I do find it useful.

Comment: @OleV.V. Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although votes can also reflect that.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I don't believe having a reputation cost for delete-voting would make people more "responsible" with their delete-votes. In addition: you get back the reputation which is lost for downvoting an answer when that answer is deleted. Assuming that also happens for the reputation you want to charge for delete-voting, that encourages people to either delete-vote posts which already have delete-votes and/or organize into groups of delete-voters, so they rapidly delete posts in order to get their reputation back. Overall, I just don't think a penalty will "improve" delete-voting.

Comment: Basically, always applying a penalty to delete-voting is **not** "a deterrent to the misuse of Delete-vote". It's just a deterrent to delete-voting in general. It would be a deterrent to misuse, if the penalty was only applied when the privilege is misused. However, that gets us back to the issue of defining "misuse" of delete-votes, which you've defined only as "coordinated Delete-vote", which is something you would actually *encourage* by having the penalty (see above).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I didn't say it *was* justified for downvotes. I said it was really unfortunate. If it is justified, it's to prevent one user unilaterally reducing the score of competing answers to favour their own answer. There is no need for that with delete votes because they can only be applied to already negatively scored answers, and unless multiple users agree, they have no effect.

Comment: I mean you have 41k rep; I'm pretty sure that rep count seems to just tick up on it's own without you really having to do any daily effort for it like answering questions. If you lost 5 reputation points somewhere, would you even notice? You'd need to go on a delete voting rampage before it starts to even really show up in your statistics in any noticeable way. It's as much a deterrent as throwing a cotton ball at you :)

Comment: Thanks, @Makyen, that helps my understanding a lot. Maybe I should post a question on meta-meta (this was a joke) about the wording of tooltip.

Comment: What I especially neither understand nor like is when a question has answers that have been upvoted by other users than the original questioner are deleted. Shouldn’t such upvotes say that the question and answers *are* worth preserving? I cannot even delete *my own* low-quality question when it has an upvoted answer. At least we should make it somewhat harder for someone else to do it too.

Comment: @Gimby granted... downvoting answers only costs 1 rep, but that fact is why i'm not past 100k, ;) also why within a year or two I may lose the ability to downvote altogether on MSE. it's certainly not completely insignificant

Comment: @OleV.V. Upvotes are a strong signal that people find it useful, but they are not enough to preserve the question in many cases. We already have functionality that makes it harder to delete heavily upvoted questions.

Comment: @Dharman And that includes (downvoted and closed) questions with heavily upvoted answers?

Comment: Just suspend [Martijn](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1378087) He is delete voting the same posts over and over again.

Answer (score 30):

I agree with points 1 and 3.

Only allowing delete-voting a given post once per user would be good to help prevent delete wars (examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65949774/timeline), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65267099/timeline)), exactly the same as the reason we only allow a close vote to be actioned once.  The first example required a moderator's intervention to put a stop to it.

Allowing retraction of delete votes is just sensible.  Posts can be improved, and humans make mistakes.  I have a couple pending delete votes that I'd retract if I could, after further consideration and/or input from others.

---

Making a delete vote cost 5 reputation is a terrible idea. We shouldn't be penalizing curators. The 1-rep cost for downvoting answers already prevents a significant amount of downvoting of bad answers.  I would imagine very few people would cast delete votes even on deserving questions with such a high cost.

As for requiring a reason, there's only one valid reason to delete a post: it has no lasting value to the community.  If people are deleting posts for other reasons, they should stop.  We don't need multiple reasons.

Comment: *Making a delete vote cost 5 reputation is a terrible idea. We shouldn't be penalizing curators.* - What is the point of penalizing the downvoters then?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I can't say for certain, but one reason I can think of is that downvoting is a privilege that is granted *much* earlier, in fact at just 125 rep. I wouldn't really call those users curators, at least in the same sense as someone who has 10k, and cares to use their delete/undelete privileges. I wouldn't be too comfortable with there being no cost to downvoting content for users who are relatively new to the site.

Comment: @cigien - Do the coordinated Delete-voters deserve to be called curators? In one of the meta-post, I had referenced 11 of the questions, for which I had written an answer, which had been deleted by the same so-called curator in a span of three days. Later my post was deleted by mods and the same so-called curator has been continuing his so-called "curation" work on many other questions for which I've written an answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash On the face of it, your question is seeking input on how the delete-voting feature should work. I really don't think the comments on this post should be about the actions of any specific user, or any grievances you might have about it. If you keep referring to the actions of a specific user, this post will look like a disguise for you to vent your frustration in that regard. I sincerely hope that is not your intent in posting this question.

Comment: I believe @ArvindKumarAvinash is asking pertinent questions about delete/undelete features. Just citing a personal experience, related to his question should not be considered as individual grievance.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, just citing an instance is not an issue, especially if it's just in a single comment, which is why I said "If you keep referring ... this post *will* look ...". The reason I'm being preemptive is that I'm aware that this is a sore point for some users, and I could see the comments deteriorating rapidly to discuss a specific user's actions. I'm just trying to avoid that happening if possible.

Comment: We should be encouraging more, and effective, curation,  not applying sundry penalties.  There are a LOT of bad questions, and a lot of ineffective curators.  Some users have issued more than 13 times more upvotes than downvotes, and that is very detrimental to site quality:(

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure I understand that argument. Are you implying that users should not vote unless they have a "better" ratio of downs versus ups? Or that they should seek out bad stuff to vote on even if they're using the site to find solutions? Or something else? I expect most users don't encounter bad Questions mainly because they don't seek them out. Also, what one finds to be bad, someone else may find to be good.

Comment: You support point 3, including: *Currently, there is no way to retract the Delete-vote if it was cast accidentally.*? Because once I click "Delete" my browser shows me a modal confirmation box where I have to click OK to actually cast my vote. I can't imagine any delete votes being accidents.

Comment: @rene I meant the general concept of retracting them, not specifically that I believe they're cast by accident with any non-trivial frequency.  I gave reasons in my answer why I believe they should be retractable.  I've certainly realized I made the wrong decision after casting a vote every now and then (sometimes with input from the community).  It seems logical that I should be able to fix my error, as I could with a close vote (or, to a lesser degree, up/down votes).

Comment: I think delete wars can be prevented in a different way: system could allow repeat votes on the same post but require delay of several days between them. This way has proven to work well with expired close votes

Comment: @gnat That's not really how close votes work.  A close vote can only be recast if it expired withoutt resulting in any action being taken.  The entire problem is that 3 users can cause a post to be deleted repeatedly, even when a greater number of users with undelete votes oppose it, which cannot happen with the close vote system.  The first example I linked shows that users are, in fact, willing to do so until forcibly stopped by a moderator.

Comment: well, delay _would_ prevent delete wars and you can't deny that. As for limitation of one actioned close vote per post, I think main reason why such crude and simple approach was chosen is that 3K close voters are dime a dosen - even if system loses one of their votes there will still be tens thousands others available to adjust to desired state if needed. There are much less of 10K delete voters though and it doesn't feel safe to ignore their votes in such a simplistic way - at least not without first trying a gentler approach with voting delays

Comment: It's not "ignoring" their votes - their vote is being countered by another 10k user.  Slowing down delete wars is not the same as preventing them.  They can just wait out the timeout and delete the post again.  If three 10k users vote to undelete a post, why should _their_ votes be ignored if the original voters are particularly persistent?

Comment: I was talking about both kind votes - and undelete ones look even more important here. We don't have that many users to review and act on deleted posts and ignoring (yes, ignoring) their votes only because their peers disagreed feels unnecessarily risky, given that we didn't even try a gentler approach with delays

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash But what if the posts are actually worth deleting? You have asked a very general question/suggestion and you receive very general answers. Now when you respond to the answers by saying that you get all your posts deleted, then what's the point in a general discussion? I feel like you have a personal interest in not having your posts deleted and this is absolutely fine. But then let's talk about the actual cases. Otherwise you start a general discussion with the premise that the posts you have in mind are not worth deleting.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Delete-vote to be cast only once

I fully agree. This feature lacks balance compared to others and might be misused.

> 2. Delete-vote cast costs 5 points of reputation

I feel the downvoting penalty of one reputation is rather psychological and prevents from gaming with the other answers. Downvoting six times a day four competing answers eventually add up. However, I still find no reason to penalize deletion voting. Separating good/bad answers/questions is one thing, separating relevant content from spam is another one.

> 3. Make the delete-vote retractable
> 4. A reason is required to select for a delete-vote

These are great proposals so far. We can retract votes for some limited period of time in case we rethink our action which happens often (at least to me). Deletion voting deserves also such a feature at least for sake of the user-experience. Also, there exist multiple reasons why a question should be deleted (if so) which might be valuable feedback for the poster.

---

Summary: In general, I am not happy with the deletion voting experience on StackOverflow. Combining ideas no. 1, 3, and 4 would help us to treat deletion rights more carefully and make the votes more targeted and transparent in terms of the reason for the vote.

Comment: *This feature lacks balance compared to others and might be misused.* ... really? There is [no evidence of misuse](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1378087) unless you think that "misuse'"  by 84 users warrants a new feature. Looking at that list I would just hand it off to a mod and suspend the top 3 to set an example.

Comment: @rene Would is be plausible that moderators double delete a post for other reasons that just general disagreement with other users? As in un-deleting to clear flags before re-deleting it? This would screw the perception of the results for them compared to other users on that list, would it not?

Comment: @Scratte I only present the data. I leave it to others to give meaning to it. Let me say that I would have been surprised if no mods would have been in that list.