# Should we stop making martyrs of highly controversial opinionated posts?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta, meta-effect

I am referring to the recent hot topic in particular:

[Is downvoting harmful and should it be removed completely?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582/is-downvoting-harmful-and-should-it-be-removed-completely)

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCMis.jpg) of the latest revision for <10k users, in case the question is deleted).

It is yet another "downvotes bad" post (still, even after the edits). It got downvoted to smithereens, closed, and eventually deleted.

That mess of a question was then picked as the subject of a *"Meta is too eager to delete"* [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-folks). That single action caused the original question to go from "quickly forgotten" to a "highly contested territory" status.

Whether you agree that the deletion is justified or not is irrelevant to the question at hand: what we ended up with is that the revision history on it now looks like a war zone:

> [image: post history part 1]
> [image: post history part 2]

Several controversial actions were taken that make me question if we are doing the right thing here. The post was:

- Re-opened before being edited into something constructive.
- Re-opened by gold badge holders while it's **very clearly** a controversial situation that no single user should force their will on... Twice.
- Re-opened despite the fact the OP clearly isn't interested in a constructive discussion.
- Re-opened despite multiple duplicate targets [clearly explaining why downvotes are an integral part of the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).
- Dragged onto Twitter, a place with a questionable understanding of how SO works and is not known for facilitating coherent arguments instead of relying on mob mentality.

---

The only reason the question is getting that much attention is that it was used to illustrate a point. This is the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) on Meta itself, and it is really making a mess of Meta curation.

So I ask you, **why don't we judge a question by its own merits?**

Please do not *reopen* such posts because you think they should not be *deleted*. Try to forget about the Meta question you were linked from and just look at the question itself.

Comment: Perhaps if it wasn't deleted in the first place, if wouldn't have made a martyr..

Comment: That doesn't matter though, now does it? The resulting question could've been written in a general sense, the link could've been left out. Users should be judging a question by its own merits, not by whatever meta question they came from.

Comment: On it's own merit, perhaps also then it still shouldn't have been deleted. The only reason why us lower users can even see it it because it was linked and un-deleted. We.. normally don't even get to see those post. Not only are we not part of the war, we're completely left out of the discussion too. How are we suppose to know those discussion have even taken place before?

Comment: Please stop talking about the deletion, that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Perhaps not for you. I'll get there maybe in 2037 where I can see it after it's been deleted. At 3K I should be able to vote to reopen such. Not necessarily because I think it should be re-opened, but because those posts get deleted as soon as they're closed!

Comment: @Scratte I’m a low rep user on SO too, and I view “being left out of the mess” as a *service*. The question was a user venting because one of his recent questions on SO had been downvoted; it sought no discussion, it never intended to make use of Meta; it was only placed here because at least Meta has people to yell at. Beyond that, it’s a topic that’s been discussed 98,317 times, and nothing has changed since the last time it was raised. There’s nothing to be said. So, the question should not have been posted in the first place, and its proper state is non-existence.

Comment: _"Not necessarily because I think it should be re-opened, but because those posts get deleted as soon as they're closed!"_ And that's exactly what's going wrong here. Pity re-open votes on, frankly, junk.

Comment: Your reputation level isn't relevant. If you don't get to see something because it's deleted, you don't get to see it. Your comments here indicate that you'd re-open junk to prevent it from being deleted... That's simply abuse. No more, no less...

Comment: I kind of feel this post is a bit ironic though. To me it comes across as another rant ;)

Comment: Oh sure, it's a bit ranty, but I'd like to think I at least make some good points there, instead of _"Downvotes bad!"_.

Comment: I'd say not re-open but un-delete the question at least so the users that do not have 10k rep can see what's going on. This does not mean people should re-open it until it's good but at least since it's mentioned in a "hot" question, so that we can know what OP is talking about.

Comment: The only reason it's "hot" is because it's a _bad_ question that resulted into a meta discussion. _"so the users that do not have 10k rep can at least see what's going on"_ I disagree. Not deleting something if it should be deleted, just so people can still see it kinda removes the point of deleting stuff.

Comment: @Adalcar Closed, non-deleted questions can still attract (heated) commentary and, apparently from what some users are claiming to do, re-open votes. If Meta drama is one's cup of tea... Gotta get sum rep.

Comment: An actual Answer would be nice. By preference, an answer that addresses the issue presented in **this** question rather than the linked example question.

Comment: Better off without martyrs, regardless of what they're made of. If we really do need martyrs, there's plenty of trolls to choose from.

Comment: I want that question Open not because I want it to be martyr, but because this way it will not be deleted, so it can continue accumulating downvotes, and I want it to be Open because we cannot get enough of good arguments on why we need downvoting.

Comment: _"I want that question Open <...> because this way it will not be deleted"_ That's not what re-open votes are for.

Comment: Isn't a lock available to prevent deletion of closed questions?

Comment: Sure, that's an option, but what purpose would it serve? It's a horrible question.... And this is kinda getting off-track again.

Comment: I'm more pissed-off at the fact that the question was closed and could be deleted; then someone with the gold `discussion` badge decided to unilaterally reopen it. Because now I can't vote to re-close it.

Comment: One thing that could be done today: tweak the HMP algorithm to not make posts so hot. HMP features posts easily get many times more visitors than non HMP posts. Maybe the selection criteria could be widened and the frequency be reduced after a certain amount of votes/visitors.

Comment: "Don't re-open junk because you think it shouldn't be deleted." But isn't this forum a place for people to have opposing opinions and not a hive mind? Yes, some people take it to an extreme, but just because you think something is junk, other people don't. I find that many people think everything is junk when it isn't. I'm having that problem with my own question. They refuse to read it because it's "too long" and had "too much info", yet "not enough info", even though they didn't read it. If there was a way to prevent DV or CV on the same Q or A for opposing reasons, your Q would make sense.

Comment: @computercarguy: 1: this is not a forum. 2: re-opening something to prevent deletion means you're re-opening a rightfully closed question when it shouldn't be. That's abuse of the privileges you've gotten. I'm not sure what your question has to do with this...?

Comment: @Cerbrus, 1: the definition of "forum" is "a public meeting place for open discussion". If this isn't a forum, what is it? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forum 2. Just because some people think a Q should be deleted, it doesn't/shouldn't invalidate other people who think it shouldn't be deleted. You call it "rightfully closed" even though there are opposing votes, so what you're just saying that all the negative votes should have more power than positive votes. Especially if you agree with them.

Comment: @computercarguy: No, I'm talking about a question that's ___correctly___ closed, but people deliberately re-open it, because they think it shouldn't be _deleted_. There's a difference between "closed" and "deleted". A question can not be deleted if it's not closed fist. Re-opening a correctly closed question to prevent it from being deleted is abuse. I don't know how else I can explain this, but I'm not saying what you think I'm saying.

Comment: It's like removing the grass from the park to prevent people from walking on it...

Comment: @Cerbrus, I've had at least one Q deleted by Roomba without it being closed, since it got 1 DV, no As, and time went by. I still needed it answered. It got DV because of "not enough info". I've since reasked and added a little more, only to be DVed and told it has "too much info". And your metaphor of grass in a park is questionable. Grass is meant to be walked on, yet people have a problem with it getting worn through and seeing dirt, having an irrational idea that grass should exist for the sake of it looking good instead of being functional.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Please stop bugging me about everything I post.

Comment: @computercarguy: Roomba is a completely different system, and not really relevant to this discussion...

Comment: @Cerbrus, except that you said "A question can not be deleted if it's not closed [first]." and I showed that it can be. If you think that's being pedantic, then you have the same problem I have with people's DV or CV when they see one problem with a post and decide the whole thing is bad. Especially when they don't explain what their perceived problem is. And extra especially when their perceived problem is the exact opposite of other people's perceived problem.

Comment: @computercarguy "*except that you said "A question can not be deleted if it's not closed [first]." and I showed that it can be*" you're missing the context which is deletion via votes.

Comment: @computercarguy: __You're talking about a different process here.__

Comment: @Cerbrus, I'm including a process that interrupts and short-circuits the voting process based on what some people think is a flawed voting process. Excluding that "different process" is part of the problem, since it's still related.

Comment: You know what, post an answer here with your take on it.

Comment: If one replaces "re-opened" with "closed" and "gold badge holders" with "three people" then this would also work perfectly the other way round.

Comment: Can we please leave the post in discussion undeleted until this (and the other two discussions about it) have ended? It's kind of strange when everyone below 10k isn't able to participate in the discussion because the source is deleted. I'm not saying the post should stay undeleted forever, just until the discussions here have settled.

Comment: @BDL Not sure why only until the discussion have settled. Without the other post, this one is useless. If we delete the other, this one might as well be deleted too.

Comment: 5 answers, a lot of discussion and this got closed as _"does not appear to seek input and discussion"_? And _"We must be open to discussions"_-George is the first close-voter of all people? I can't be the only one that finds that just a little ironic...

Comment: @BDL: Imo, this question still stands without the linked question. This is about the meta effect. The content of the linked question isn't as relevant as the (screenshotted) history is.

Comment: Irony is that this Question author which is using the other post in their argument, has continuously deleted the other one. Lots of the Answers are also referencing the other post arguing that it's a good or bad example. How can anyone read those not knowing what the other post actually contains?

Comment: _"arguing that it's a good or bad example."_ those arguments aren't about my question. They're about george's question. The deleted question's further existence on this site really has no effect on my question's relevance or answerability.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I think we disagree about this. You characterize the other post as "another "downvotes bad" rant" which people disagree with. It should be up to everyone to judge this themselves. To be honest, I don't find this post here being less ranty than the original post. I also do not think it is more inviting for a community discussion than the original post. So I could either try to delete this post and the other one, or keep both open. I went with the later option.

Comment: I refer you back to my earlier comment: _"Oh sure, it's a bit ranty, but I'd like to think I at least make some good points there, instead of "Downvotes bad!"."_ I'm not making wild assumptions, I'm not demonizing the entire curator userbase... Frankly, I find it a little insulting that you compare this meta question to that "Downvotes bad" rant.

Comment: I find it seeking input equally to the other one too. You don't seem to want to budge at all. Just like the other Question author. And if the number of Answers determines if a post should be kept, the other one has 10 of those. Twice the amount that this one does.

Comment: @Scratte Fwiw, the only reason I answered that one is that people insisted on re-opening and undeleting it. If it's gonna have to stay, the least I can do is explain why every single point made in there is a horrible idea, or a gross misconception... (I mean, undeleting I _get_, but re-opening that? Really?)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Several other people wrote on more than one occasion that this is in their eyes not the usual baseless "downvotes are bad" rant. It (at least) tried to bring in arguments on why they think downvotes are bad. Wrong arguments, sure, but it's not "baseless". And I really don't like that the comment thread here devolves into personal attacks. What would you react be if someone leaves a comment speculating about the motives of a close-voter under some other question?

Comment: Wait, where did I resort to personal attacks? _"baseless", "wrong", "misguided"_... Semantics.

Comment: @Cerbrus [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405665/can-we-please-stop-making-martyrs-out-of-junk?cb=1#comment828810_405665). Of course I did it too when mentioning that this author is deleting the other post, despite using it in their own post.

Comment: @Cerbrus *George is the first close-voter of all people? I can't be the only one that finds that just a little ironic* -- and that's not personal?

Comment: Well, thanks for triplicating that personal attack, guys... I don't really agree, but okay. Sillyness aside, next time please just flag the comment instead of drawing more attention to it.

Comment: @BDL - sorry, but I think this is a strawman's argument you are making here. George is involved in these discussions as much as we all are. Besides, there is a kind of conflict of interest because they *did* bring up the question that instigated the current discussion. And then they cast the first close vote on this one as "not seeking input", which one *can* find ironic and is in their right to do so (I am not saying this is that of a problem). I really don't like we are starting to pull the "unfriendly or unkind" card here, can we please not read into comments more than they contain?

Comment: *"Re-opened despite the fact the OP clearly isn't interested in a coherent discussion."* - that point really makes me say "So what?". In these kind of meta posts I am rarely really interested in what the OP themselves have to say, I am only interested on what others have to say about it, especially among each other. If they vehemently disagree with everything... big whoop, they're a single voice. That does not affect how I myself am influenced and informed. I just wish it wouldn't be such an easy trigger for deterioration though.

Comment: @Gimby: If it were a constructive discussion, I'd agree, but that question was born out of a personal frustration with downvotes... If the OP then doesn't want to listen to explanations on why the system is what it is, imo, the whole point of that question is gone.

Comment: @Cerbrus - you should probably update the question to include the most recent version of the post history - now it is certainly a war zone... I wonder if it is time for a brave kamikaze moderator to undelete and lock it for good. By now it holds a record of being the most-disapproved non-mod/non-SE post shy of a suggestion to monetize SO - which is a message in itself if you ask me.

Comment: I voted to close [because the OP even stated the purpose of the question as a PSA to tell people to stop inducing the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405665/can-we-please-stop-making-martyrs-out-of-junk#comment828450_405669).  That's an announcement -- that's not something that is meant to invite discussion -- and in fact when I answered the OP was upset that I had done so, further inviting that the OP didn't want community feedback! (which is itself a close reason, and the close reason I chose).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: This post being an "PSA" is _your_ interpretation of that comment... I don't like your answer because you're not answering the question. You can spin this any way you want, but to me this just looks like you're looking for excuses to shut this discussion down. Which is, as I stated before, ironic.

Comment: @OlegValter: I'm amazed it hasn't had mod intervention other than that first instance, indeed... There's at least one flag pending on it, requesting a lock. I'm don't think increasing the length of the screenshots further really adds much, a mess is a mess, already.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm now also close-voting this question since the original problem post has been deleted again. If we don't want to have a meaningful discussion, then sure, let's go ahead and stop the discussion.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Then accept that you don't get it and move on. Stop bugging me.

Comment: @BDL: That question being deleted or not does not alter the value of this question...

Comment: If anything, the linked question makes a great argument for delete and undelete votes being limited to one per type per user per post.

Comment: @yivi: I agree. I was contemplating posting a _"Make deletion and closure function similarly"_ suggestion, but that's a little too much to keep track of now. :D

Comment: It [has been suggested very recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405534/does-the-delete-undelete-vote-feature-need-to-be-revisited). Some of the points on that question are bad, but some have merit.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I wasn't serious about including more of it in the post, sorry :) Since some took an issue with the post looking like a statement and seemingly not inviting community input, I edited it to try to convey that it does - I am no Shog9, so please do feel free to rollback in its entirety, especially if you feel the edit conflicts with your intention.

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for that edit, that's actually much better :D

Comment: Suggestion: coherent --> courteous. I think that better captures the problem of the user's attitude.

Comment: Or constructive, actually :D

Comment: @jpmc26 No, I think "coherent" is the correct word here. Maybe it's *a little bit* strong but it's still in the same ballpark. OP wasn't being completely consistent. They brought up some stuff as criticism of downvotes that came out of the left field and weren't really correct, either. Like claiming that downvoting is classical conditioning.

Comment: @VLAZ: irrational as they might be, technically, those lines were coherent. I’ve edited the question a little, but I’ve not replaced all of’m... I felt “courteous” would be a little too fancy.

Comment: @Cerbrus are we talking "coherent" for communication, like "intelligible" as in the words and sentences used are correct, or "coherent" as in the argument as a whole, where the argumentation, examples, and conclusions are consistent? Because I was referring to the latter. I found the argumentation to be disjointed and inconsistent. However, I do agree that saying OP couldn't formulate sentences or communicate in a manner that cannot be comprehended is absolutely not the case, so rewording here was probably good to avoid painting OP in an unintended light.

Comment: I was implying the latter, but I can understand that being misunderstood, so understandably, I opted for a explanation less open to interpretation, to prevent misrepresentation. (:D)

Comment: @VLAZ In the absolute strictest of senses, I would agree in principle that downvoting is intended to be a form of conditioning. Voting and the associated reputation *are* supposed to be a reward/punishment mechanism that influences your behavior on the site. Atwood talked frequently about "gamification," and that's pretty much an attempt to tap into exactly this psychology. But it isn't being used as some kind of nefarious brainwashing technique as the user's tone suggested; it's to encourage good content and discourage poor.

Comment: @VLAZ As for "coherent," I think the word is better avoided here precisely because it has multiple meanings and connotations as you describe. That sort of flexibility leaves the door open to people with opposing opinions arguing about different claims, and arguing past each other is unproductive. I suggested "courteous" because it seemed more precise and less trite to me, but "constructive" works absolutely fine and shouldn't produce any confusion here.

Comment: @jpmc26 classical conditioning re-wires the response from one stimulus to another. So, it's *shifting* some behaviour to be a response to a previously unassociated stimulus. Pavlov's dog experiment is the founding one where dogs were conditioned to salivate at the sound of a bell. I do not believe we are trying to do anything similar with downvotes. What both you and OP refer to is *operant* conditioning which can reinforce a behaviour by introducing a behaviour. The experiment that established it clearly was the Skinner Box.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not saying they got all the details right. I'm just saying it didn't sink to "I like turtles" levels of relevance; I can understand what inspired the remark.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a tough one. I feel that if I just combine the two answers that I wrote on recent events into a summary here, this will pretty much answer this question in particular.

#### [A: It is time that we have a Super Downvote!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405590/it-is-time-that-we-have-a-super-downvote/405617#405617)

Judging a question by its own merits includes employing our curation-wise votes when, and only when they should be applied. We don't have strict guidelines for when to vote up and down, but the criteria for closure and deletion are *supposed* to be stronger. **Educate** our users on these votes, and provide better **communication tools** on Meta to facilitate discerning wheat from chaff. Quoting:

> Improve our guidelines and criteria for distinguishing Meta discussions worth keeping from those that should be taken away. From yesterday's incident, it is clear that we don't quite have a consensus on this. [...] even a thoughtful and concerning question can be the source of unnecessary drama and unwarranted soapboxes for ill-posed opinions.

In other words, we can, and maybe now should, look for ways to boost the value of Meta as a platform to assist in maintaining the site and propose features. This in turn should help the community use curation tools more effectively.

#### [A: Can we slow down on the deletes on Meta, folks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-on-meta-folks/405631#405631)

Although question deletion is known to be fast on Meta, sometimes even unnecessarily, the linked question is a terrible example of it. Despite the clear signal through the massive downvotes that the proposal is bad, the way not to martyrize misinformed users is not to turn their questions into a drama show.

And since I wrote these before noticing the re-closure *and* re-opening of the linked question, an addendum: As much as we understand that some people would like to observe a question after it's been deleted, it's a *serious* problem that people are voting to reopen questions with the single purpose of keeping a circus active and/or visible for longer. That is not in accordance to our curation guidelines, and as per the nature of the question, is a disservice.

One can only wish to have a silver bullet, but this subject is neither new nor easy. For what it's worth, Stack Overflow has still stood ground against other online venues related with programming and software development. This weekend, we have heard voices advocating change. Let us reach a compromise to continue investing in the platform. Do not fear change, but fear the consequences of those changes. So long as proposals are discussed constructively and standing on prior work, we should be fine. Time could even tell that the current Meta format was a mistake, who knows.

But until then, please use your votes properly, and protect the site from these emotional uprises.

Comment: Thanks! It certainly isn't an easy problem to solve, as what we'd have to solve is basically user behavior... You make some good points about education and communication!

Comment: Why would people be voting reopen in order to undelete, instead of voting undelete? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Cerbrus For a [discussion] question that has only 2 answers, and which was posted just a couple of hours ago, is accepting an answer so soon commonly done? I'm not saying you've made up your mind already, but I think waiting a while for other answers might make it look like you're more willing to change your mind if there are valid arguments put forward.

Comment: I can always change the mark if a better answer shows up :-) this does answer my question, though, and I think it’s a very good answer.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm not sure I follow your comment. There were people in the comments in this question hinting that they would vote to reopen questions, so that the reopening would cancel the deletion votes and so keep the question visible and active longer.

Comment: @E_net4wantsmoreflags ah, I thought you meant already-deleted questions. There's probably a design issue in the system there, but I have no idea how to improve it. The problem will get worse the more eager a small number people are to delete things.

Comment: "Please use your votes properly". Sure.. everyone will agree with that. Only we don't agree what properly is.

Comment: @Scratte We _do_ agree on at least some of what _improperly_ includes, and have some tools available to mods to enforce them. _Properly_ probably includes following the tooltip prompt in when to vote, either way.

Comment: there is the question of should 1 person moderator or gold badge holder closing or reopening after it's gone through a re-open or close vote be allowed? IMO successful votes should override 1 person's actions and prevent further single-person interventions. and the whole point of that system is close, edit to be better and ask for re-open then if voters agree it should be re-opened but once a single successful vote has gone through it really should prevent single user dictators. the fact is to be able to vote to re-open or close requires a decent amount of rep already.

Comment: @Barkermn01 I'm afraid that goes both ways. It takes substantial effort in a subject matter to obtain a gold tag badge, and substantial trust to become an elected moderator. If moderators were not allowed to perform moderation unilaterally, it would kind of break the purpose of having moderators in the first place. For gold badge holders, this would be a different story. That could be expanded separately, although the risk of skewed operations could become higher.

Comment: This is IMO Moderators are voted for by the community to act on the community's behalf, performing actions like this against the community should not be allowed, but gold badges especially they have not been voted for they have just performed well inside that tag and that's good work but does not mean they are "The expert". but it still comes back to democratic rules and democracy should not be prevented on a democratic system. moderators most certainly should moderate Terms violations though.

Comment: "voted for by the community to act on the community's behalf" - agreed, but we as "the community" are not always right (and certainly are not that homogenous as the term implies), so moderators being able to make unilateral decisions (and sometimes controversial ones) is good as long as we, collectively, can call the moderator out for their actions should they be found objectionable.Fully agree on the part about gold badgers (but that comes down to shortcomings of Meta being an afterthought)

Answer (score 48):

So since I'm one of the gold badge holders involved in this, I'll explain my rationale in full.

I take *extreme* umbrage to this phrase:

> **Can we please just judge a question by its own merits?**

...because this implies that somehow I did not do this.

In context, questions complaining about downvotes or why someone's post was downvoted are about as prevalent here on Meta as hydrogen is everywhere else.  A pattern that I've noticed over the last four or five years has been this kind of negative spiral:

- Someone's upset about downvotes, so they come to Meta to voice their frustration.
- If their frustration is *constructive*, their question is closed as a duplicate explaining in general why their question was closed as a dupe.  Then the question might get deleted.
- If their frustration is a rant, then their question is unceremoniously closed *and* deleted, thus fomenting the frustration all over again.
- Eventually, someone makes their way over to social media to whinge about how toxic we all are.

Rinse, wash, repeat.  We've been down this road a million times.

The thing about this is that I'm not all that bothered by people running to their favorite echo chamber to add yet another stanza to the already thick Book of Grievances: Stack Exchange Edition.  I'm *more* bothered by the fact that Meta seems less interested in actually helping someone out in a more personable setting when it's not as expensive to do so.

Note that on Stack Overflow proper, there are some 40 million questions.  It isn't feasible to try to engage with every individual there because those questions are myriad, and technically, a lot of them *are* bad, or *are* dupes.  It's not difficult to point to an answer about null pointers in Java if they're using Java and their code exhibits the same pattern of how an NPE would manifest.  But on Meta, I make the conjecture that duplicates are seldom duplicates unless they *literally* rehash the same thing.

Yes, I get that your impression of the question is...well...

> Don't re-open junk because you think it shouldn't be deleted.

...which is something ***else*** I take umbrage to.

If you take nothing else away from this, at least let me convey this:  **Until Stack Exchange gets its act together and actually explains what downvotes are in a way that is digestible for the community at large, and why people might get them, *we're* forced to deal with that onslaught of questions here, on Meta, instead.**

I have argued, successfully in the past as well, that the reason that there is this frustration is that it's more borne out of the fact that someone got their question downvoted and is frustrated about the experience.

Well, we can't do anything about the experience, so I don't bother exerting energy on that.

What *is* in my span of control is a way to help talk through their specific question and help them understand what they can do to improve their individual question instead.  That may be the limit of what I can do, but I've always felt that I've had more impact in being able to do at least that.

The convenient thing to do in content moderation is to find a way to not answer the question, which is...actually pretty unfortunate to say the least.  There are questions asking for feedback or improvement that are buried underneath some discontent or frustration about the process which can either be edited out or reclarified.

To the point of...

> Re-opened before it was edited into something coherent.

...it's because there was no time to do that before it fell off of everyone's radar.  I said this much in a comment justifying this to you.

> I think you're overstating the verbatim lifecycle of salvaged questions.  Basically - if a question is deleted, that adds a lot more mental burden to bother with trying to bring this question back from the grave. The best chance a question has to survive is if it's salvaged while it's still undeleted, because people will still be around long enough to evaluate the revision and agree/disagree with it then. By the time it gets into the review queues, it's very often too late, especially for posts on Meta.

To further add to the mess, there is no review queue for deleted questions, and so a moderator would have to get involved to undelete the question.  I would imagine that they'd be hesitant to do so in the face of the (unfortunately one-dimensional) signal that they'd look at with respect to the question: it was heavily downvoted.

To my last point, this is a self-fulfilling prophecy, ironically enough...

> Dragged onto TWITTER of all places (I'm not gonna link this), a place well known for understanding how SO works and forming coherent arguments, instead of going all mob mentality on an issue. /s

So [because this was someone familiar with Meta](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1365414371334193159?s=20), and someone who has had a history of doing this (which I think is fine tbh), the circumstances change a bit.  But the pattern still applies.

The OP originally brought this question to Meta [a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400312/its-way-past-time-to-end-downvoting-op-questions) (thanks to Martijn for that link) and it was nuked from orbit.

They came *back* with something similar.  Y'all tried to nuke it from orbit again.

For the record:  **I would have absolutely no problems closing the new question as a duplicate of the old question**, but I would also resist deletion.  In this context, the old question *really* was a rehash, whereas any other existing "here's why we downvote" copypasta doesn't taste as good.

I definitely did not remember the old question, but the pattern is all too familiar.  Someone tried to come to Meta to talk about this.  They got rejected by Meta.  A discussion about why this happened or why this was okay is being [actively rejected on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405669/1079354).  So...where else does one get to turn to talk about this?  What, did you think they'd just be...okay with being unable to discuss their frustration about the site?

[image]

My philosophy on this is pretty simple.  It does take a bit more time and energy to help someone understand why Stack Overflow works the way it does.  This is why Meta exists.  If Meta doesn't want to help others explain the situation, then we create these exciting opportunities where people get to fuss about it on Twitter.

You don't want that?  We've gotta facilitate that here.  Also too, Stack Exchange Inc. needs to get its act together and provide us with explanations about these downvotes already.  [We've been operating unsupported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354) for far too long.

---

As an additional thought, as I've been thinking about this a bit after reading some of the comments:  maybe it's better to just *answer* the question as opposed to try to facilitate a conversation in comments.  That's another pattern I've seen but I've been [flayed alive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367562/1079354) for suggesting that limiting comments was a good thing.  But ironically enough, it proves out the point that there's more than enough friction in the comment thread to start a proper bonfire. Maybe that's the part that needs to cool off.  Disagree with the question all you like; that's what downvotes are for.  Getting into a shouting match with an OP because they don't agree with your viewpoints?  Not nearly as constructive as a structured yet firm answer explaining the viewpoints of Stack Overflow as you understand them, or your opinion on why their suggestion is flawed or full of misunderstandings.

Comment: In regards to twitter: _this_ question was dumped on twitter before the first answer here was posted. Same for the "delete-happy meta" question. It was not in response to being rejected on meta. Now I'm all for helping people understand how SE works, but it's painfully obvious the OP of that question is not interested in the explanations provided. I didn't mean to personally accuse you of the different "misbehaviours" (aside from my opinion that it'd have been better not applying mjolnir here)

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised @Cerbrus.  Yet more evidence that we don't like helping folks out from an outsider's perspective. :|

Comment: The one that posted it to twitter isn't an outsider...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Got a link?  Would love to read it so I can correct myself.

Comment: It's a me, Mario.  [I posted it on twitter](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1365414371334193159?s=20). Not sure what the rancor is there though -- some people use meta as their soapbox; some use twitter.  The post got steam because my original post ended up on HMP. That's the source of its popularity, not that I lamented the behavior of meta-veterans on twitter.  There's about 10 people who follow me on twitter who even have enough reputation to do anything on meta; and there's no guarantee they even all saw it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I'm not giving twitter ___any___ credit in regards to traffic or popularity. I just think it's a horrible platform, and it's caused a ___lot___ of problems for SO, and Meta in the past. Posting meta discussions to that "echo box" is just poor etiquette. Posts get taken out of context, and it wouldn't be the first time if the Twitter army came barging in.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sunshine is the best disinfectant, as they say.  (Also, if the argument is "People will be upset at what we do if someone shares that with them" then you're not making the point you think you're making).

Comment: Here we go again. Remember what I blew up at you about, recently? I'm done talking to you.

Comment: I think the point about this being pulled onto Twitter isn't surprising though @Cerbrus.  It feels like the same circumstance though; some frustration about how Meta works can be expressed on Meta because Meta doesn't want to facilitate the discussion.  Where else is it gonna go?

Comment: Meta _does_ want to facilitate the discussion, though. It's just that the opinion of the majority of Meta is one they disagree with. They also chose a very bad post to make an example out of.

Comment: For some reason I'm not seeing that...it feels like this is still aimed at somehow passing some kind of decisive moderation on the content to make it simply go away.  I think that the other Meta question about why this was deleted was plenty to discuss this in, but we've got another post.  I suppose I should've asked this from the beginning, but what's your goal @Cerbrus? Do you want to delete the original question that started this mess, do you want to understand the rationale of someone like George or myself why we'd not want it deleted, or do you want something else?

Comment: I want people to stop re-opening junk because it's mentioned on meta. The ___only___ reason that question is still alive is because someone decided there ___has___ to be a discussion where clearly the OP isn't interested in what Meta has to say. What remains is a trainwreck of a question, even after all the edits, it's no more than a bunch of baseless rambling. It's a _bad_ question. This is that Meta-effect that has to be stopped.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I don't know how you qualify a question like this as *junk*.  Maybe we should start there.

Comment: Yet another “downvotes bad” rant with an OP that doesn’t wanna know how downvotes work... Dime a dozen.

Comment: So...you're *not* seeing that as an opportunity to engage with the OP to correct them on their thinking @Cerbrus?

Comment: It was very clear very quickly that that wasnmt gonna mean squat. I have yet to see an question like that turn out to have an OP that was actually interested in discussing it.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I have some examples in my meta answers.  There are a handful of OPs who do discuss it, but they may choose to leave the site altogether if they don't find that satisfactory.

Comment: We’re days into this and the OP in question still doesn’t appear to be interested in discussion. How long do we need to give this user the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: *"If their frustration is constructive"* - I would have stopped there really. It was not.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli:  So you missed the entire other half of my decision tree there, did you?  But even in this case I would have argued that the criticism post-edit was constructive and could be discussed as opposed to dismissed out of hand as just a rant.

Comment: You answered their question then. You answered their question now. Δ = 0. Nothing has changed. Start recognizing the rants (not you, just in general),. Start recognizing those that can't be helped. I can appreciate you _care_ and I believe that the site wouldn't be as successful as it is without your contributions, @Makoto. **Your** opinions (about that powers that be) have merit and deserve discussion and I will amplify them wherever I can, but let's _please_ stop indulging these fruitless posts.

Comment: @Makoto well, I'm just saying I would have employed a different decision tree, that's it.

Comment: For some very strange reasons, I've had a lot of fun reading through this answer. It felt... nice? Understanding? I don't know how to put it. Frustrated, yet, gentle.

Comment: I can understand how you would take the wording of this question personally. I get how reasonable people differ, esp about deletion. But the OP in the question we are discussing used words like "malicious", "cowardly", and "toxic". Language that is mostly *still* there, now, *after* all of this. Somebody rolled in to our community and said "your values and norms suck and so do you". Why do we have to host that assertion? We're not talking about sexism, sarcasm, or other things *actually* toxic, we're talking about *downvotes*. If that qualifies as toxic now, I will wear the label *with pride*.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  It's not that I'm not recognizing the rants.  Far from it.  I feel like a lot of content moderation being done here on Meta is missing the forest for the trees, though.

Comment: I'll break this up since it's long @SotiriosDelimanolis:  First, I mentioned and still assert that I would have been fine with closing this question as a duplicate of their other original question because that genuinely did cover the same ground.  Because it was deleted, we lost the ability to do that.  No one's going to bother raising that sunken ship just to close this question as the dupe.

Comment: Second, @SotiriosDelimanolis - by simply deleting the question we don't like interacting with (e.g. the second question), **we're losing a whole ton of valuable information and signal** that we could use etiher as a future dupe target, or as evidence to showcase how and where the education of users of Stack Overflow needs to be improved.

Comment: Third, and probably most importantly @SotiriosDelimanolis: The action of deleting or removing these kinds of posts really demonstrates my earlier point.  It's convenient in content moderation to simply not answer the question.  Note that this is all I said:  not answer the question.  I answered the question and didn't tend to engage much further with the OP on it.  There seems to be a tendency here on Meta to get everyone to either comply or perish, which isn't the mentality you have to have when you're trying to teach or guide.  It accomplishes the opposite, actually.

Comment: @JaredSmith:  I already explained why we have to host this assertion:  because the company doesn't give us anywhere else to do it.  "Toxic" seems to be a trigger word for you, but for the record I only ever saw it once in the question.  Furthermore, it's a common stereotype of us users of Stack Overflow: that somehow we're toxic.  I've gotten over that a long time ago, but I can see that the scars are still fresh for you.

Comment: @Makoto I don't care if people *outside* call me toxic for trivia, but they had better do it in a cesspool like Twitter that I can safely ignore as completely irrelevant rather than busting *in* to our nice walled garden. As for "because the company doesn't give us anywhere else to do it", why should they? This isn't about bad stuff, it's about *downvotes* which as others have pointed out has been done to *death*. If the OP cared *one whit* about our values, he/she would have done their homework, and *at least referenced prior discussion*. It was just an ignorant rant, pipe it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I really like the last paragraph you added in your answer, about discussions in comments. I'm guilty of it as well, but there's some commenters on the question here (and meta in general) that should really just post an answer.

Comment: This answer is worth a gold bar for every word ;)

Comment: Re *"on Stack Overflow proper, there are some 40 million questions"*: One count is *[20,908,059 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest)*. The [highest post ID is 66,448,884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448884). That doesn't seem to add up (maybe I am wrong). 21 million non-deleted questions, 19 million deleted questions, and 26 million answers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen because of caching many ids are reserved but never used for posts. If the stack software crashes ids are lost without ever being associated with a post.

Comment: I agree that we should, *in general*, be willing to explain things to people. However, on that point, there are two important facts to note. First, this question *was not* an example of this. The user clearly demonstrated their motives were otherwise. Secondly, a closure doesn't necessarily preclude some explanation: comments can still be left and a chat can be started. This particular question was a dumpster fire and rightly deleted, in my evaluation. I think a better option if there was something novel here would be to siphon it off into a new question and point this user at it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "Also, if the argument is, 'People will be upset at what we do if someone shares that with them,' then you're not making the point you think you're making." That isn't the argument. The argument is that people are denigrating something they don't understand and have no interest in understanding, and they're attacking us on the basis of something that's not true. In other words, Twitter is amplifying a prejudice. It's the internet equivalent of a public lynching (and no, I do not make that comparison lightly): no trial, no defense, just hatred and assumed guilt.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker And now having read your tweet, I see you *contributed* to this prejudice. Your tweet is essentially a call for Twitter to pick up their pitchforks and torches. You yourself have abandoned any attempt to understand those who disagree with you here. And you want to chastise *us* for being unwelcoming? As I said elsewhere: the "welcoming" ideology is pure hypocrisy, and your behavior is exhibit A of that.

Answer (score 17):

> Can we please stop making martyrs out of junk?

Apparently not.

I honestly don't think this is ever going away, and for the same reason that the question in the question being questioned (i.e. should downvotes go away) is never going to go away: it's a political question. Subjects only make it on to the political spectrum if there is a fundamental irreconcilable difference of opinion about them.

There's a [figure-ground inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure%E2%80%93ground_(perception)) at play here:

1. In one view of the world, Stack Overflow is an open platform. Everyone, *and their content* has a *right* to be here, and that right should only be revoked after they prove beyond any possible doubt that they/it should be removed. Many (but not all) who hold this view seem to also believe that any denigration of content is a denigration of the individual, and an abrogation of their right to access this platform. Any impact on quality is noise not signal; process cost of growth and inclusion.
2. In the other view, Stack Overflow has a very specific mission. Users are granted probationary acceptance at first, and must *earn* their way by posting quality (as judged by the community) content to ensure that mission is carried out. Instead of having to prove you don't belong to get kicked out, you have to prove that you *do* belong to stay. In this worldview content is judged on its merits *alone*, and any implication on the poster is simply melodrama that has no place in Serious Business TM. Any impact on exclusivity is noise not signal; process cost of maintaining the qualities that made this platform desirable in the first place.

Obviously these positions contain a bit of caricature for the purpose of setting up contrast, but I really think this division is at the heart of a lot of these debates. Because people looking for the first kind of platform are going to have an allergic reaction to the second, and vice-versa. What is noise in the first view becomes signal in the second, and likewise in reverse.

You can say that adopting the first view will cause this site to turn into an ongoing dumpster fire of un-curated junk, and I will mostly agree.

You can say that adopting the second view means that only people with apparently higher-than-average psychological fortitude can participate, and that this is exclusionary, and I will mostly agree.

It's a tradeoff, and which ever side we end up on *some* people will be unhappy, and they will complain, and they will try to nudge the ship of state in the direction of their preferences, much like IRL politics.

Comment: This is probably the best answer, and summation of the real problem, to be found on meta. As user 4 years into my probation (610rep at this writing), I'm of the 2nd view and would really like to see corp make moves to help in a) affirming that view in current times (as opposed to the ancient writings of the founders), and b) providing guidance or tools in explaining that to those currently holding the 1st view.

Comment: There is a common fallacy that could apply here, namely seeing two peaks when there is only a single spectrum. I would like to see more evidence that people are really divided (in which case maybe StackOverflow should be simply split in two versions: WikiStackpedia and OpenStack) and not just have a single broad spectrum with a peak somewhere in the middle between the two extrema, in which case a compromise would be best.

Comment: @Trilarion I think IRL politics is also more of a spectrum than what one would think from e.g. consuming the news media. But when it comes time to decide policy, that spectrum gets condensed into a binary choice (e.g. Trump or Biden). It seems that a lot of the people more towards the second end of the spectrum would like to enforce norms more stringently. As for the other end, the charitable view is that they want more inclusivity, the uncharitable view is that they want to turn SO into yet another battlefront in the omnipresent culture wars. SO as it exists today *is* the compromise:

Comment: ...[cont] with the CoC we made a big (and necessary!) push to combat actually toxic behavior like sarcastic comments (e.g. RTFM, LMGTFY), assuming people with neutral handles are men, and misgendering people. We've rolled out initiatives to help new users. We've tweaked the wizards, the UI, etc. At this point, I don't know what to make of what's left: these people can't handle *downvotes*? How do the handle code reviews/performance reviews/adult relationships? Do they not have jobs? Do they still live with their parents? What's the deal here? Am I just missing something? I really want to know!

Comment: @JaredSmith For 13 years we kind of optimized within the local optima we are in, never really making any big steps away from the initial state (and the success proves it was good). We could argue that this is simply the best, but we only have done local optimization so far. We would need controlled experiments with vastly different conditions to be more sure about being at the global optimum. Basically invent yourself new every day. Ask yourself how you would do it if you would have to start again. You really never felt the sting of a downvote?

Comment: Last point first: on SO no not really. Over on politics.SE, lots. The difference is, to me, instructive: political beliefs are *personal* (obvs) but I can't even begin to get into a mindset where my question about file handles being closed as a dupe causes me to go on an anti-SO crusade on Twitter. Technical feedback is just different. I'm frankly having a very hard time here not just rounding this off to some sort of stereotypical youngster coddled special snowflake participation trophy ism. Because I can only imagine taking it that hard is if *it's the first negative feedback I'd ever had*.

Comment: @Trilarion [cont'd] As for your point about local vs global optima, maybe? Hard to see out of the valley you're in. But we have some natural experiments in the form of Quora, Wikipedia, and forums. Quora has the dial turned too low (opinions are like ***holes, everybody has one), Wikipedia has it turned too high (must be this tall in order to contribute), and forums are as Robert Harvey put it a "vast wasteland of suck". I'm not sure we can do more than incrementally better than we are? But I'm willing to try some more rigorous experiments.

Comment: I fully agree there. I just wanted to make the point about the difference between people believing this is the best possible way (because nobody else is obviously better) and being sure that it will also stay like this because we tried everything possible and nothing else was better. It's kind of the effect that people with a good tool might stop searching for a better one.

Comment: And I don't mean more "I hate downvotes" questions like the one mentioned here. I mean that we ourselves should question more our own assumptions. We should continue to develop a theory of downvotes and everything and should think about alternatives and about ways to prove the value of downvotes in practice. Maybe along that way we will find some surprises. Don't stop experimenting.

Comment: 'only people with apparently higher-than-average psychological fortitude can participate'....in software development.  That I can agree with.  I don't wish it, I don't try to enforce it.  It just is, as anyone who has sat in front of a terminal on Sunday moring, reviewing yet again logs and debuggers, trying to understand a system bug that must be fixed by Monday to demonstate a $70m milestone, will understand:(

Comment: @MartinJames yes. I am constantly surprised that other people are surprised when they find out that programming is *hard*. Like, what did you think they pay us for? And that too has implications for SO: is it desirable to act as a weeder to filter out people who won't be able to cut it? Because if you can't handle a downvote on an internet forum, you don't have much chance of debugging that mission-critical thing when millions are on the line. IDK, when we say we're for "professional and hobbyist programmers", where do we draw the line with "hobbyist"?

Comment: @JaredSmith Wasn’t it “enthusiast” instead of “hobbyist”? For me, “enthusiast” means that you’re _willing_ to dig into documentation, specifications, tutorials, etc.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you're probably right, and I totally agree

Answer (score 16):

I've probably followed all two and half meta threads, 2 twitter threads and...

Maybe we're all taking this too seriously.

There's no way we're *really* going to get traction for an actual core mechanic being changed without some absolutely rock solid, inspiring arguments. If we didn't give it as much attention as we did, it would have sunk into obscurity, maybe getting roombaed as no one even bothered to answer it.

Yet here we are, arguing over a post no one *realistically* feels will cause meaningful change, arguing for its own sake, caught in [an ant mill of drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_mill).

Clearly the deletions were ineffective, as were the closevotes. But the post is also at a very high negative number of posts, since people obviously broadly disagree

At this point it would take a particularly <strike>foolish</strike> brave mod to pick a side, and possibly lock it.

While meta is a discussion space, lets not lose track of the fact that discussions for their own sake may not be the best thing. We need discussions that actually critically and constructively bring up potential weaknesses and improvements in this system.

I don't feel the original post was (though I eventually felt I needed to address it). And if the issue was with the excessively quick deletion, would letting it sit a while been better?)

We're currently at 2 posts too many on the issue though

Comment: In my defence, I have a night shift and am waiting for other people to reboot servers :D

Comment: I don't think the post in question is really the essence of all this. From where I'm at it looks like it's about censoring what can be discussed.

Comment: It is the essense of everything going on around this question IMO

Comment: The interesting question would maybe why we all took the question so seriously? Somehow it seems to invoke strong emotional reactions, either way.

Comment: Exactly. Deescalating at any point likely would have resulted in a quiet death

Comment: *There's no way we're really going to get traction for an actual core mechanic being changed* - I think everyone discussing closure/deletion agrees on that, and that the only reason to leave it non-deleted is so future readers can see the massive amount of downvotes, i.e. community consensus that it's not a good idea.  I don't have a strong opinion about closed / open.  This answer seems to assume that deleting totally non-viable proposals made for unclear reasons is definitely what we should do.  I don't think that's obvious; meta is different from the main site.

Comment: Note for the foolish moderator: if you delete it, nobody can undelete it.

Comment: Ah, but then someone will post on meta to why its deleted.

Comment: Sometimes the only way to stop dumpster fire spreading is to let it freely burn to the ground. For every action there will be another overreaction and you cannot break the cycle.

Comment: Well or to deprive it of fuel. Letting it burn can be suboptimal too. Alas I suspect shog might have a better firebreak analogy

Comment: @Scratte I really don't think this is about censorship. I haven't seen *anyone* argue that changes to downvoting can't be discussed. Rather, the main problems I've seen cited are the inherently hostile attitude of the user posting that question and the fact it really doesn't bring anything to the table that hasn't already been hashed so much that it's a purée. We all know the voting system has shortcomings, but the approach this question took is just more of the tired old, "You're bad and should feel bad," the company has been spewing at us for 2 years now.

Answer (score 13):

> Re-opened before it was edited into something coherent.

This isn't some troll post. Edition 1 was perfectly coherent and it is a sincere question. Everyone ought to be welcome to ask a question on meta without having been around for 10 years and without spending unrealistic amounts of their time searching for duplicates before posting.

> Re-opened by gold badge holders while it's very clearly a controversial situation that no single users should force their will on... Twice.

Yes, well these kind of posts should generally be "hands-off" by everyone until they settle. If moderation is necessary, it is best left to diamond mods. Jean-François Fabre♦ tried to fix it apparently, I'm really not sure why his lock was overruled.

I have questioned the legitimacy of gold badgers on meta several times before (and then I'm one such beast myself too). Just because I have a gold badge in "Discussion" it doesn't make me some "Master of Discussion" who can decide what topics that are to be discussed. This is abused quite often.

If anything, having such a gold badge should make you much more careful when closing things as dupes on meta.

> Re-opened despite the fact the OP clearly isn't interested in a coherent discussion.

I'm not sure that this is all that clear. Controversial or not, we should allow things like this to be discussed. Even if not the most constructive post out there, it may be good to just look at things we take for granted from a different point of view now and then.

Sure, it might have been discussed before and there's no point in beating the dead horse, but if so use a *recent* duplicate as link and only if the linked question is actually of better quality than the current one.

> Re-opened despite there being duplicates that clearly explain why downvotes are necessary.

Closing the post as dupe to some old one from 2014 is highly questionable. SO is a living beast where rules and culture changes over the years. We can't go make some calls "no you aren't allowed to discuss this because we already discussed it back in 2014". That's neither democratic nor relevant.

> Dragged onto TWITTER of all places (I'm not gonna link this), a place well known for understanding how SO works and forming coherent arguments, instead of going all mob mentality on an issue. /s

Those who read Twitter get what's coming to them. I couldn't care less.

---

So to summarize, you are basically asking why people have different subjective opinions about moderation than your own subjective opinions. While you are out there yourself tossing around subjective delete votes left and right.

Even closing discussion as "opinion-based", seriously? I didn't even know that close reason existed on meta. *Obviously* it should not be abused here since it was *obviously* only intended for the main programming Q&A.

Comment: (Small footnote: I didn't vote for "opinion based" there, but for "not open to discussion", I believe the majority close reason shows there. I agree that "opinion based on meta is, well, silly)

Comment: This answer hits all the right notes.

Comment: The opening post here has been edited; "coherent" has been replaced with "constructive" for clarity. I think your first point is based on a bit of misunderstanding. (Mind you, I'm not blaming you for it. The original choice of word didn't quite communicate what I think Cerbrus intended.) You may want to update.

Comment: @jpmc26 The correct way to deal with question edits that render answers incorrect or obsolete is question rollback.

Comment: @Lundin No, clarification is valid. The question's intent has not been changed (especially at a fundamental level), just made more manifest. If you don't want to edit, you don't have to. I was just letting you know in case you have some different thoughts as a result.

Comment: "If anything, having such a gold badge should make you much more careful when closing things as dupes on meta." I also thought about it, and while it's true I think it should not mean that one cannot use the powers at all. For example, for many years I wrote lots of contributions that were well received and that now means that whenever there is something controversial I probably shouldn't vote in order not to get criticized by someone. That would be basically less than the deal before. I used it, I got immediately asked for an explanation, I decided to give it. I think that's ok.

Comment: @Trilarion Or use the trick: Remove the tag, put your 1 of 3 duplicate vote on it, re-insert the tag.

Comment: @Scratte Another common approach is to wait until your vote would be the last one, then cast it. That way you're only using your elevated vote as a single one. Mods use this strategy, too.

Comment: @Trilarion It's a very different closing some support FAQ as dupe and closing a discussion though. For a discussion to be a valid duplicate, it must have been discussed fairly recently - basically the person wishing to discuss something must be able to go the thread you point them to and pick up the discussion there. If it's some cold case from 2014, well... there's no way to meaningfully bump that thread alive again. Also, diamond mods, unlike us gold badgers, were community-elected to handle exactly these kind of situations, so we should let them deal with it for that reason alone.

Comment: @Lundin "For a discussion to be a valid duplicate, it must have been discussed fairly recently - basically the person wishing to discuss something must be able to go the thread you point them to and pick up the discussion there." Stack Overflow as a platform rejects that premise, though. We intentionally *do not* support customizing a discussion of a problem for a particular user. We are designed to curate the meat and bones so that users can learn the material and figure out for themselves how to apply the skin to their particulars. That's as true for Meta as it is for the main site.

Comment: @jpmc26 The difference between the main site and meta is that the main site is 100% about existing things. Meta can have discussions about things that do not yet exist, of features we'd like to see or rules we'd like to change. There's nowhere on meta you can go to learn and study things that do not yet exist or have never been tried. In this specific case, there's no case study you can go and check what would happen if we remove down-votes, because it has not been done on any of these Q&A sites.

Comment: @Lundin I fail to see how that's relevant because this post didn't suggest performing an experiment. It just insisted that downvoting is immoral and useless and should be removed with extreme prejudice, a premise the designers of the platform *literally and explicitly* rejected to define the foundations. The notions that downvoting is immoral or useless have been addressed ad nauseam. And the user who wrote it went around denigrating users, insisting that downvoting consistently comes from forms of malice. There was nothing constructive *or* new there.

Comment: @Lundin I feel it's important to expand on the difference. A post in which someone suggests an experiment is one that fundamentally acknowledges that the effect may not be as they intend; in other words, they're open to the possibility they may be wrong. Such a post would also have to acknowledge the history of the site and the fundamental role downvoting is intended to play because it would need that information to refine the hypothesis and make suggestions about the construction of the experiment. And it would likely take care to acknowledge strongly held opinions to garner more support.

Comment: @jpmc26 Actually, it has to my knowledge never really been properly addressed by someone thinking outside the box. The whole idea with SO is to use public shaming as a moderator tool, which in turn has many flaws. Most notably, people respond very poorly when criticized in public. Especially when down-votes, close votes and comments just keep piling up, beating the poster over and over. You may not think it is done with malice, but the natural human reaction is to respond as if it was, to get defensive. It's hard to argue against it being a system designed to create as much drama as possible.

Comment: @Lundin Okay, that's a fair argument that at least warrants a response. And if this question had been titled, "Does SO's downvote system *create* drama? Is it worth keeping if so?" we probably wouldn't be having this discussion. I'd expect some insightful answers arguing both sides of that discussion. The question that got closed/deleted wasn't *anything* like that. The user literally [associated downvoting with racism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582/is-downvoting-harmful-and-should-it-be-removed-completely#comment827727_405593).

Answer (score 6):

There's [this joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/567jwg/the_year_is_2028_and_rjokes_is_going_strong/) on the /r/jokes subreddit (slightly edited for readability):

> A new user gets on to r/jokes and sees the most upvoted joke just says
> "28". The second most upvoted joke says "3915". The third most upvoted joke says "756". He can't see why they're getting so many upvotes, so he comments *"These aren't jokes, they're numbers!"*.
>
> The admin replies *"You must be new here. r/jokes has been around for
> so long, we've seen every joke, so we just refer to them by numbers
> now"*.
>
> The new user wants to get a few upvotes so he creates a post saying "504,323".
>
> When he checks his account the next day his joke is the top post on
> reddit and the most upvoted r/jokes thread of the last 10 years. He
> messages the admin *"What happened?"*
>
> The admin replies *"Nobody had heard that one before"*.

I've addressed this issue four years ago in [Can we talk about the reviewing culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta). My observation was:

> it appears to me that an small crowd of 5-10 relatively low-rep (5K-20K) people are active in the review queues on Meta, and they are down-, close- and delete-voting everything that they don't like, while they (again, this is how it appears to me) hardly ever participate posting actual answers on Main.

It's like the reviewers *still* go *"Oh no, not question 321 again"*, and go hunt for a nine year old question they remember because they were around when that got asked, downvote, dupe-vote, close-vote and wait for the next question to come in on Meta that they can review.

I still agree with Makoto's answer there:

> I believe that it's fair game to downvote a question here on Meta, especially if it's not an ideal approach to a problem, is ill-researched, or is just plain ranty, but I don't really like deletion of questions here unless it's absolutely necessary. Save for users mistaking* the site for Stack Overflow, there are ***very few questions*** which actually need to be deleted.

So please, stop delete-voting. You're deleting new hallmark posts, you're making Meta a nasty place, and you're stopping people who aren't on Meta for 24/7 to see what other users are trying to start discussions about.

If people would stop deleting that much, we wouldn't have the occasional *"Can we please stop deleting?"* post, and therefore no "martyr" posts on which the Meta effect is applied, as is tradition.

Comment: _"You're deleting new hallmark posts"_ I would agree, if that new post were constructive. Trash in, trash out. That said, (to me) this reads like an answer to _"should we delete?"_, not as an answer to _"stop making martyrs"_...

Comment: My point is: if we don't mass-delete, we also won't have recurring "please don't delete"-posts, and therefore no "martyrs". It's like you're asking _"Can we not apply the Meta effect to Meta?"_, which is, of course, impossible.

Comment: But that boils down to whether or not we think deletion is okay or not. Imo, the problem here is that people post meta questions just to make a point, but use a extremely poor example in there, resulting in edit wars on that question. If you want to make a point, fine, but the meta effect it causes should be avoided, somehow... For example, by not linking to the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster "*if we don't mass-delete, we also won't have recurring "please don't delete"-posts*" if you really want to go down that line of reasoning, then if people don't post poor discussions, then we wouldn't need to delete them. Now, is this really where you want us to go? I don't think so. Can we focus on whether the question was bad or not first and *then* talk about how it was handled. Because talking about "X way to handle things is bad" while omitting what and why was handled by X is re-framing the narrative.

Comment: I originally wasn't sure how I felt about deleting this particular post. However, as I looked more at the content of it and the attitude of the user who posted it, I agreed with it. This question was doing little more than inspiring animosity on both sides, and it was *set up from the beginning* in a manner that fostered such an outcome. All the user did was denigrate downvoting and downvoters without even having a working understanding of its history and norms, and then the question's supporters essentially claimed victimhood for being such down over such an approach.

Comment: I have no doubt that a more courteous, open minded suggestion with more acknowledgement of downvoting's purpose and uses would have been vastly better received, even if it was still heavily downvoted for disagreement. As I told the author in a comment: welcoming and kindness cannot be a one-way street.

Comment: ^ The last paragraph of this answer an the first 4 comments here were screengrabbed and dumped on Twitter... I do _not_ appreciate being talked about in a place I'm not going to contribute. It's rude, and it's attacking us in a place we can't defend ourselves.

Answer (score -5):

This question is asking the wrong question (Sorry, in order to answer your question I have to reject the premise, that the problem here is people fighting over this question).

The natural conclusion of "Why are we fighting over junk" is "Just let it be", that is, if we didn't want to have a fight is that it should have just stayed closed and deleted.

So yea, I can't even accept the premise as valid -- that as soon as 5 people vote to close and 3 people vote to delete that that's that.

That aside; one reason this happens is that some mainsite features should be used sparingly *if at all* on Meta.  This post exposes problems with two of them : closing (particularly as a 'duplicate' or closing as 'opinion-based') are problematic cudgels wielded to shut down conversation people with the reputation to close and delete do not like.

Closing and deleting conversations that fall into this are especially problematic for the community as a whole.

I [explained why in my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-on-meta-folks) but I didn't go into the nitty-gritty of why the software should not be used in this fashion.

First off, [using the main-site software for Meta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/28/cmon-get-meta/) started out as an experiment: [image] (image in case we lose the blog again), and here's the text of that blog post:

> **We’re a little unsure how well the current SO engine will map to discussion-y topics**. Remember, we **designed explicitly around Questions and Answers — specifically, questions around a theme that can be (mostly) answered!** Launching our own internal meta-discussion site is **one way of finding out**. (emphasis mine)

in case that's not clear enough, the blog post ends with the YOLO of the day:

> We’ve made a few of the easier changes already that were based on (groan) meta-data. Others will be tougher. We won’t know until we try, so …
> C’mon get meta!

> … and see what happens.

In case it's not abundantly clear; this was an experiment.  No one knew how the software would work. And in the beginning it wasn't soo bad.  Now, 13 years later, we see its flaws.

One of those flaws is the fact that duplicate closing exists on meta.  If you can't discuss a policy more than once, **why even have a meta site?**.  You don't need one. You can throw it on a blog post, turn off comments, and call it a day.

The second flaw is closing questions as 'opinion-based' on meta.  *Where else* would we put opinions, if not in a place where we should be discussing and *enacting change*?

Now deleting is even more problematic; especially when it's done so quickly.  No question short of actual spam, gibberish or political hate speech should be deleted that quickly on a meta site.  It may be a bad question; and we may hate it, but that doesn't make it hate speech.

Part of the problem with deleting it is if it's truly a duplicate than how do we point someone to a recent conversation on the topic?  The listed duplicate was seven years old, and wasn't even really a duplicate.  Wherever the threshold for "Can we discuss this again?" is, it needs to be on a better time-scale than once every 8 years, especially for a meta site; where the community's mindset shifts yearly, if not more often than that.

So, to answer your question with a question: The discussion shouldn't be on "Why are we fighting over junk?" It should be on, "Why do we not want to let people have discussions that are fundamental to the continued health of the site when we disagree with the premises of those questions?"

Or

"Why are we so hostile to the concept that people will discuss change?"

I think both of those would yield far more interesting answers that delve into the psychology of people who spend their time on meta, and would give us far more to work with when discussing how to change meta features to better reflect the purpose of meta as a way to discuss and enact change.

Comment: You're not answering my question about judging a question by its own merit. You're answering your own question about deletion here...

Comment: @Cerbrus I answered it in the first sentence. I reject the premise of your question.

Comment: Then the answer should've ended there instead of going on a irrelevant tangent about deletion

Comment: "Why are we so hostile to the concept that people will discuss change?" - We're not, we're simply hostile to users that don't grasp the basics of how the site works but rant on meta that they want them changed. I also reject your premise that the 1001st post complaining about downvotes is somehow "fundamental to the continued health of the site". I might even reject your premise that the question which triggered this is anywhere close to a discussion, given that OP does not seem to have learned anything or contributed much except "downvotes bad" for the last two days.

Comment: @Cerbrus  As per my answer, it's relevant to state why this happens and why we should probably change the meta software to keep it from happening.    You want people to stop doing something the software let's them do, and I am explicitly saying "Let's change the software".

Comment: @l4mpi with 1001 posts on this topic; perhaps one from this year could have been used as a duplicate as opposed to one from 7 years ago?

Comment: No, you're abusing my question for your own agenda, going as far as _dumping it on twitter_, repeating the same old tired _"we must be able to discuss things!"_ argument.

My question is about the ___meta effect___, the behavior of users.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you keep repeating that, but I don't get it. If your problem was a bad dupe target, ok, select a better one, or even create a canonical if you think none are satisfactory. If your problem was the _age_ of the dupe target - the arguments from 7 years ago (even 11 years ago) are still valid, so I reject your premise that age is a problem.

Comment: @l4mpi the arguments were valid *to you*; but not necessarily to the larger community, as evidenced by how many people are speaking up in favor of keeping it.  The software and the community are not static; and answers on a meta site should not be treated as such. All it does is create an insular community that can't adapt; which is the chief cause of death for a community.

Comment: If the "answer" is not about the question, perhaps the "proper" question should be asked by you directly, and let _that_ discussion carry it's own thread.

Comment: "I cannot answer _your_ question, so I'll ask and answer my own, using yours as a vehicle." Somehow that doesn't seem like the proper way to have a discussion, in any context.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I would be inclined to agree with you more if you didn't choose a pathologically bad example of a question/topic as your hill to die on. Discussing downvotes ad nauseum (or rather, explaining to ignorant users why downvotes are neccessary, and should not require you to comment) is NOT integral to the site, and even auto-deleting all questions that contained the word "downvotes" would not even come close to having as much influence on the health of the community as all the misguided things SE did over the last two years.

Comment: @Cerbrus You've stated "Whether you agree that the deletion is justified or not is completely irrelevant." in your question. Are we to take that as a fact? Or is it allowed to disagree and post arguments against your statement?

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: Considering this question is about _reducing the meta effect_, specifically on meta itself, whether or not the deletion was warranted isn't a subject of this question. Judge a question by its own merit, instead of by the question that was written about it.

Comment: Also, I find it very very ironic that the same person that didn'd see any problem with deleting troves of comments on meta now fears for the health of the site if we don't let users rant about downvotes every day...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If you think people are too close/delete happy on Meta, that's a fine thing to raise awareness about. However, the question you chose was quite possibly the worst option available of all currently deleted posts. It was an nth duplicate, uninformed, and a rant. If that kind content isn't what close and delete votes are for, even on Meta, then I don't even know why the features exist on Meta in the first place (and no this is not an invitation for you to say "they shouldn't!"). The focus of this seems to be about *the question you chose as your example*, not your cause in general.

Comment: @TylerH I'd love to point out a better question; but given how delete happy people on meta are, it'd be nearly impossible to find it without access to the Dev Database.  It's a convenient excuse "You should pick a better question to defend". I and others would be able to, if you all would stop deleting them within **36 minutes of them being posted**.

Comment: @cerbrus if your question isn't "Can we not make martyrs out of junk?" and it is "Can we stop having a meta-meta effect", perhaps you should change the title of your question? Although the latter is suspiciously close to "This does not seek community input", and thus should probably be closed.

Comment: Making martyrs out of junk is happening because of the meta effect... My title's fine.

Comment: @cerbrus then I guess you'll just have to accept that you'll get answers you don't like.

Comment: @Cerbrus also the engagement on twitter is so low as to be non-sensical as the 'cause' to this.  There are maybe 10 total people that follow me on twitter that have voting rights on meta. Maybe 10.

Comment: And back to the beginning of the circle: You reject the premise of my question and go off on a irrelevant tangent. This is your que to reply saying meta software needs to change.

Comment: @l4mpi I find it ironic to mention other actions by a poster of an answer on a question asking to "Can we please just judge a question by its own merits?".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't buy that; you don't need a specific question in the first place, but if you did, surely you would want it to be a *good* example. The fact that you only raised it after a quite horrible "question" seems to lead us to the conclusion that this isn't actually a problem.

Comment: @TylerH Right. Because it's far more likely than this isn't an issue than it is likely that meta deletes questions in 36 minutes.  The evidence of the latter destroys any evidence to prove the former is wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [No it doesn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete). And if you see such abuse of good questions getting closed/deleted, flag that for a moderator to handle... because that's arguably abuse. But people voting to close and delete *nth duplicate rants* is not abuse, even if it's on Meta. For what it's worth, I support the idea of occasionally re-testing our theories/policies in a thoughtful manner as time goes on. The post in question... wasn't that.

Comment: @TylerH All that deleted tab shows is how often it's happened in the last 30 days; not how often it has happened on meta.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Right, but if you're concerned that it's happening so frequently that it's risen to a level of abuse, you should see plenty of examples even just from the last 30 days.

Comment: @tylherh even once per month is abuse.  The problem is, we just don’t know.

Comment: I'm very new to stackoverflow, in terms of a registered user although I use it for two years now. Although I have some experience in ML, Python and R etc.. I definitely do not know enough...god beware..thus, sometimes in these 2 years I thought I wanted to ask a question and to register...but I was always afraid of asking question, because of getting downvoted and marked. And I still have the same feeling, even for answers. I looked at the original posts, and I have to admit downvotes can be educational. But sometimes, you scare people.

Comment: "...closing (particularly as a 'duplicate' or closing as 'opinion-based') are problematic cudgels wielded to shut down conversation people with the reputation to close and delete do not like." This is precisely the bad faith assumption that led to the problem post in question. You're using a circular argument: content moderation is bad, therefore people moderating content must be bad, therefore content moderation is bad, ad infinitum. And note that this argument itself fundamentally violates the CoC.

Comment: @PatrickBormann Downvotes and closure are not to be feared. Yes, they're a little unpleasant, but if you have some idea what you're talking about and are willing to put in the work, chances are you can write a question just fine. And if you get some, I promise you can grow from it. If you're well and truly worried about it, I suggest a different tact: try *answering* some questions first. Joining in on a problem someone else framed is easier that starting from scratch.

Comment: You are right, but sometimes it feels well not rewarding if you deep dive into someones problem after 1 hor finally solved it or have a another workaround and get even no comment, or much worse, invested 1 1/2 an hour to find no solution just hints why it didn't work..You may be right. I will continue helping ppl on stack overflow and keep trying to answer questions. Thanks that at least someone cared!

Comment: "First off, using the main-site software for Meta started out as an experiment..." Just because it was started as an experiment doesn't mean the arguments in favor SO's design don't apply. The fact is that downvotes have been discussed ad nauseam, and this hostile post brought nothing new to the table. That situation is *exactly* what the duplication feature was designed to address, and deletion was designed to eliminate content that's creating problems without any significant gain, which also applies here. These features were applied *appropriately as intended*, so this point is irrelevant.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "even once per month is abuse. The problem is, we just don’t know" -- Looking at the /questions feed a little while ago, I chanced upon [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405882). Posted five hours ago, closed as a duplicate, deleted five minutes ago. That is completely anecdotal of course, but I suspect that were I going to ping you every time it happened you'd become annoyed pretty quickly.