# Discussion on discriminatory user behavior

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, specific-user

I would like to bring SO Community's attention to one critical issue, that I'd noticed on this
thread [Deletion/undeletion battles - should moderators step in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406320/deletion-undeletion-battles-should-moderators-step-in) where one user (I would not prefer mentioning their name)
made discriminatory comments (which remain deleted now), because of flagging comments.

In the user's answer **region and race** were specifically mentioned which was edited by another user; the answerer then put back those racist comments. I must say **I was/am appalled and deeply shaken :(** by that.

I see that the user is suspended now and I really appreciate the mod's actions here.
I had seen this user making comments on race, region, skin that were very offensive and disturbing.
In my humble opinion, SO Community **should have banned that user**. **I would like to ask the Community members/mods here would you NOT have done so?**

Remember the 'George Floyd' shameful incident in the US?. We all stood as a society against it.
It was a racist act; I feel Stack Community must **act against those who DO NOT believe in the equality of all humans.**

Considering the user had posted offensive and derogatory comments multiple times against a specific race/region/community. I would like to hear from SO Community that the suspension of such a user a good enough punishment?

I love Stack Overflow and I  urge all to make it a place that recognizes the dignity and equality of fellow human beings at the same time agrees/disagrees with them honestly.

Comment: FYI, we are not Twitter - neither rants are met with a welcome response. nor we tend to subscribe to mob mentality and go lynching others (well, the latter part may be sadly farther from the truth than I think, but that's just sad). We also do not "ban" people as banning/cancelling/removing [choose your own flavour] only serves in locking the punished in deviant behaviour, whereas the suspension gives them time to cool down and then come back.

Comment: *We also do not "ban" people...* @OlegValter That's not strictly true. There have been instances of users being suspended for so long that it's effectively a ban.

Comment: @BSMP yeah, I know there are some cases where the duration is so long it is actually a ban, but these are, to my knowledge, the rarest of exceptions - I did not mean to say SE doesn't have a way to make the penalty permanent (like account destruction in certain cases), but that permabans are not the way things operate (if this has changed, would be nice to know)

Comment: Was the offending user a member of some standing, or a 'Member for today' troll?

Comment: I don't like to see it as banning or suspending people, I like to see it as protecting the knowledge base from misuse. Sometimes it needs to be shielded from a particular individual's modifying interactions for as long as the knowledge base will exist.

Comment: FYI not many people know who George Floyd was. Most of us don't live in US and while we sometimes hear about some of the problems people there are facing we don't all follow closely what's going on.

Comment: @Dharman well... BLM was and is a world-wide thing and George Floyd became a figure head in it. I willingly live under a rock and even I was well-informed.

Comment: @Gimby Some people don't remember names well. So while they may have heard about the whole BLM situation, it is quite possible that knowing the name(s) of the people involved is different story. Just saying.

Comment: About that particular regex tag discussion two users belonging to same geographic area were being accused for deleting conspiracy, and it is very likely that mentioning another geographic area in relation to users that were undeleting questions was nothing more than showing similar "geographic grouping" pattern and was not meant to be offensive in any way. Person was suspended, but we don't know the actual reasons. I cannot tell you not to be disturbed and offended by what was written there, I am just offering you different view on what possibly happened.

Comment: We should not allow political or other prejudice on this site at all.  That includes both racist comments and speculation about some incident and/or court case on the US.  Once you start on that path, you will never get rid of the trolls and SO will be dragged through the mud on social media, yet again, with the usual 'I say SO is bad, so it's bad' unsubstantiated fake news.

Comment: A suspension on SO can depending on the duration be equivalent to a ban.

Comment: Re *"region"* (several instances): Do you mean *["religion"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/religion#Noun)*?

Answer (score 22):

The user was suspended by a mod.

If the user does this again when the suspension expires, they will face a longer suspension.

I don't see what else should be done here...

Comment: One thing I would personally add is: Don't take stuff on the internet personally. Imho, if you're _"appalled and deeply shaken"_ by someone saying a certain ethnic group behaves a certain way, regardless of them being wrong or not, I would strongly suggest looking at those statements in a different light: A silly opinion by a silly person. I can tell you it's much more satisfying to think _"lol that's dumb"_, than it is to be offended.

Comment: easier said than done, specially if you're in a privileged group.

Comment: This is gonna be controversial: Imho, it's easy to be offended. Being offended doesn't solve anything, it just ruins your day. Now, if you can instead ruin "their" day by showing them you don't give a **** about their silly opinion, I'd say that's a lot better :D (Always de-escalate first tho... If that fails, at least don't let them get to you)

Comment: I'm a little offended that you would suggest when I should be offended, and that you would minimize offensive acts as "_silly_."

Comment: @adabsurdum You're free to laugh at me and think my opinion to be a silly one. Note that I'm not saying you _can't_ be offended. I'm just of the _opinion_ that there are better ways to deal with situations like that. __In my opinion__, the case illustrated here _is_ silly. The focus that user has on the nationality is silly. It's ignorant, it's petty, and it certainly isn't worth anyone's energy to get offended over. But that's just my opinion...

Comment: @Cerbrus -- note that I did not say that you said that I can't be offended. When someone feels genuinely offended by something, it is pretty tone-deaf to respond by patting them on the head and telling them that it is silly to be offended.

Comment: I'm not saying it's silly to be offended. I'm just saying that I'm of the opinion that there's better ways to deal with confrontations on the internet.

Answer (score 13):

I don't like it that you decided to pick on one user due to their mistakes. The user has received punishment. It is not your job to moderate users. If you see racist comments then flag them for moderator attention and leave it up to them to talk to the user and suspend them if necessary. We have established processes to stop trouble makers and if need be delete their accounts.

Moderators don't ban users permanently unless they repeatedly abuse the code of conduct or engage in activities that destroy the site.

If you want to respect other people's dignity then stop talking about their suspension. Have mercy and hope that such users will learn from their mistakes and stop breaking the code of conduct.

Answer (score 12):

I think the length of time this user was suspended is appropriate, if it is their only recent infraction. I'd rather foster the idea that people can learn and improve themselves than ban people for all of eternity.

Temporary penalties encourage users to learn and improve rather than forcing them to start fresh with a new account and helps promote keeping a clean account history as you'd want to protect the investments you've made into your account. Having that account taken away at the first hint of trouble ruins that, especially for accounts that have been active for more than a few days.

What someone believes isn't relevant, only the content they post here is. If they can refrain from presenting such discriminatory content in the future, I see no harm in them returning after a suspension.

Comment: What was the length of the suspension?