# What should we do when a question in another SO language-site has a duplicate on the main site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, languages, attribution, international-sites

For example, someone asks a question on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ that already has a duplicate on the main site, but the OP does not understand English.

What should we do here?

I think there some possible solutions, but I am not sure which ones are okay here:

1. Close the question as a duplicate of the English question (and don't care if the OP can understand English)
2. Answer the question in the site's language. (But what about plagiarism? Because the answer comes directly from someone's answer in English)
3. Answer the question in the site's language with some explanation along with a credit (with link) to English site.

I just want to know in case I can someday open up a new site for my local language.

Comment: This should probably be posted at https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ rather than here.

Comment: @Lundin Because of the example I used? I am not referring to any site specifically. This is a general question.

Comment: The first option is not only not possible technically, it shouldn't be an option. It's true that the OP is not our main focus when answering a question (we answer for the many future visitors of the page), but just as the OP, it is very plausible to assume that many visitors of the language-site are not English speakers and hence duplication closure to the main site (if was possible) does not help anyone... The best way to go is answer with proper attribution if you translate an existing answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218048/is-it-ok-to-translate-and-repost-stack-overflow-questions-answers-in-different-l  on SE Meta is related and probably the more general use than here on SO Meta.

Comment: @MagnusO_O That raises another question "What to do when a question in another meta-site has a duplicate on MSE?" ^_^

Comment: @holydragon If it's not specific to any site then meta.stackexchange.com. Either way it is a non-issue for stackoverflow.com since we don't tolerate posts in different languages here.

Comment: My vote (without reviewing any policies) goes to your **#3**, as long as you have enough subject matter knowledge to judge the quality of the different language answer you refer to.

Comment: Another related MSE post: ["_Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/997587).

Comment: @MagnusO_O I agree this is a duplicate of the Meta question you linked. meta.stackexchange vs. meta.SO is already a very subtle site-selection question in my opinion. And this question has already led to better answers than the duplicate, anyway.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. You can't close questions as duplicates on other sites.

2/3. You should always try to answer in your own words instead of just directly translating the other site's answer. The majority of your answer should not consist of material from another site (even translated), and should add additional supporting information. If you quote (even translated), you should always provide [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) to your source material.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it is part of the mission of every non-English Stack Overflow site to increase their knowledge base to include solutions in the specified language. To the point that each site has a dedicated help centre page with guidance for translating posts from English Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange sites. For example, the one on [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)

Comment: If there is a succint, excellent answer in the main site, I fail to see how we "should always try to answer in [our] own words", instead of just translating the excellent answer.

Comment: *If you quote (even translated), you should always provide proper attribution to your source material.* Please cite good sources even if you do not directly quote or translate from them.

Comment: @zabop CC BY-SA allows copying in whole with modification, so it's actually fine to only translate, but I'd do it as a community wiki myself; I posted [my own answer expanding on that](/a/421722/4518341). From what Samuel said, I'm inferring they'd disagree, but .@Samuel if you want to incorporate anything I wrote, by all means :)

Comment: @zabop Yes, there is no reason whatsoever to reinvent the wheel. Just ensure the translation is good quality. I've translated [Henry Ecker's link in my own answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421749/1048186)

Comment: @wjandrea I disagree that the translater should not receive credit. If you take the effort to pipe something through Google translate, read through the text, ensure the text is reasonably accurate, cite the original source, and perhaps tweak a few things that are off in the original answer, it is reasonable to claim the translation as your own work.  Of course, if you just copy the link, throw in a minimal Google translate translation, it would be _far_ better to make this a community wiki.  But I doubt you are doing this anyway.

Comment: @Josiah Please comment on my answer if you want to discuss it. What you're talking about is not relevant to Samuel's answer and I don't want to clog their notifications :)

Answer (score 35):

Frame challenge:

What if we reversed this question to ask if we should close as duplicates any questions on the English SO site if an answer can be found on another site, such as Russian, Chinese or Spanish. How helpful would that be to those who only speak English?

Would a search engine be able to even find that question or answer? I understand the link from the duplicate would be a way to find the dupe target, but I find answers (and questions) more by direct link from a search engine than through a dupe link. (I'm even assuming that many of the questions I reference are dupe targets.)

Would a translation engine be able to convert it and the code effectively enough for people to actually understand it? With the way I've seen even popular online translation engine work, they don't always work well for technical stuff, especially coding examples. Trying to navigate the difference in sentence structure just adds mental overhead to something that may already be at someone's mental capacity for a topic. Even with 10 years of professional experience in C# and other programming languages, I sometimes have trouble understanding the concepts in some of the English SO answers, and that's my native language.

If we close as duplicates any questions that are already on the English SO site, what real value do the other languages sites have? I haven't looked at them, but I'd have to assume that none of them have nearly as many questions as the English site does. Then, if we start closing those questions and point to the English site, how many novel questions are left on those sites? Are there enough to justify those sites existing, especially if the majority of them are just duplicates? If you continue down this route, you end up shutting down those sites and have just the English only SO site, which doesn't serve everyone as English isn't a universal language that's taught to everyone. And when you consider that, SO would become a very obviously biased site that excludes many people from around the world and would become a target for even more accusations of discrimination [than](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398117/why-has-stack-overflow-been-publicly-silent-about-race-issues) [it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406856/discussion-on-discriminatory-user-behavior) [already](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) [is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators/334577#334577).

Comment: I really like the detailed explanation of why ***not*** to close as duplicate to the main site, but this is a partial answer as it doesn't actually answer the question which is what ***should we do*** with those questions. Still, again, very well explained why not to duplicate to main

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I thought partial answers were allowed. Even the top voted answer is technically a partial answer, since it doesn't include what is in this or the other answers. Also, I did help answer the question in that I eliminated at least their #1 option to close as dupe, and also implied that linking to an English answer isn't helpful, which is part of the OP's 3rd option. "Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction. " https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 11):

### Community wiki option

*Following from [Samuel Liew's great answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421708/4518341):*

If you want to add an answer that's only a translation of an existing answer or answers, and doesn't add any content or only adds very little, you can opt to make it a **[community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)**. That means:

1. You don't get reputation for votes on it.

   - Since it's wholly or mostly a copy of someone else's work, it's polite to not take credit for it.

     I've done this myself (not translating) if my answer is mostly copying from [someone else's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625235/4518341) or [now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70807289/4518341).
   - Although, on the other hand, the translation is your work, so maybe it's fine if you do want to take credit for it -- I'm not sure.
2. Other people can edit it more easily. That could help if:

   - the referenced answer(s) gets updated. Others can translate the updates and copy them in.
   - your translation could be improved. Domain-specific terminology and jargon can be especially hard to translate. (On that note, by the way, it's probably best not to attempt a translation if you don't know the subject matter.)

Lastly, of course, the [CC BY-SA licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) does allow copying content in whole, but [proper attribution is always required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). It can be as simple as a little note at the bottom of the answer. I like to put a note in italics with a horizontal line above it (`---`). And you should mention that it's a translation.

---

### Advice from the other language sites

- ES: *[¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)*

  - Google Translate: [Should I translate questions from English to Spanish?](https://es-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/translate-from-english?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp)
- PT: *[Posso traduzir perguntas/respostas de outros idiomas para o Português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)*

  - Google Translate: [Can I translate questions/answers from other languages ​​into Portuguese?](https://pt-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/translate-from-english?_x_tr_sl=pt&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp)
- RU: [Следует ли переводить сообщения с английского языка на русский?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)

  - Google Translate: [Should messages [posts] be translated from English into Russian?](https://ru-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/translate-from-english?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp)
- JA: [英語版サイトの質問や回答を、日本語に翻訳しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)

  - Google Translate: [Can I translate the questions and answers on the English version site into Japanese?](https://ja-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/translate-from-english?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Comment: IMHO community wikis should be used only when 1) the post author is looking that low reputation users be able to edit the post without having to pass through the suggested edit review queue **OR** 2) as part of a coordinated effort to collaboratively feed quality content i.e. a new site in private beta. I personally don't like that "only translation" answers be set as community wiki "by default" as a translation implies work and skills. It might be OK if the author used an automatic translation tool as part of a coordinated effort to collaborativelly improve that translation.

Comment: @Rubén Do you mean using automatic translation as like a jumping-off point? I.e. you have it do a first pass, then you go through and manually fix any mistakes?

Comment: It will be a lot more easy to develop the "idea" if you have a specific case (I put *idea* quote enclosed as this was already discussed in [es.so]).Do you have in mind a specific answer to be translated or a specific "duplicate" question (means that you already identified the "duplicate target" in SO) in an International site?

Comment: Let me simplify my first comment to the minimal: This answer requires more work. P.S. The discussion about set a translated answer as community wiki in an International site should be done in the corresponding per site meta.

Comment: @Rubén Sorry, I have no idea how that's relevant. I'm just asking you to clarify what you meant about automatic translation tools.

Comment: The site https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english states this (among others): 1. "The author of the translations receives reputation. Translated questions are equivalent to [the answers in own questions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) *([translated version](https://es-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/self-answer?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp))*. Please use this system to contribute to the knowledge in Spanish on the site." and 2. "Improvise: When translating, you can merge several answers into one and thus create a canonical answer."

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: If the question is good, answer it following the site policies, workings and culture. If there is something to be fixed, suggest an edit  / edit the question, again, following the site policies, workings and culture.

If the question was posted on Stack Overflow en español, if it's not already associated to the "duplicate target", associate it. If you know Spanish, for details see [Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/65).

---

While SO is the Stack Exchange Network (SEN) flagship community:

- Being an SO member doesn't make them a member of other communities. Even being a member of other communities, reputation, badges and privileges aren't transferred from SO to any other site. The same applies to International Sites members. So if someone wants to be able to vote to close, first they have to earn the corresponding privilege on the respective site.
- The model and participation policies are the same across all SEN sites, like the policy about plagiarism, but the workings and culture are not the same across all of them; some might have subtle differences but other might have big ones. Specifically, regarding International Sites, besides the language differences, each of them  have their own workings and culture. If you are interested in participating on one or more of these sites, please read

  - the help article about translating questions from SO on the corresponding site. (While the help articles are very similar, each community might have customized the initial proposal.)

    - https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english
    - https://jp.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english
    - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english
    - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english
  - Look at the corresponding International Site meta for *"associating" local questions with SO questions* posts, like [Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/65).
- If you want to discuss how to handle non-English "duplicates" of an English Q&A, you should discuss that on the site where the "duplicate" was posted, not on SO.
- General Meta questions, bugs and requests about the International sites "belongs" to Meta SE.
- Questions about new sites "belong" to Meta SE and/or Area 51
- Requests for new sites belong to Area 51.

  Note: Requests for new International sites are no longer allowed, until further notice. Ref. [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/133145)

Related

- [Is it OK to translate and repost Stack Overflow questions/answers in different language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218048/289691)
- [Is it OK to crosspost Stack Overflow questions, now that the Portuguese SO is open?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218055/289691)
- [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691)

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly legitimate to simply translate an existing answer, as long as you cite your source.

To quote, [in translation](https://es-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/help/translate-from-english?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US), [the Spanish guidance](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english) [mentioned previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421707/what-should-we-do-when-a-question-in-another-so-language-site-has-a-duplicate-on?cb=1#comment935873_421708):

> ### Should I translate questions from English to Spanish?
>
> **Of course!**
>
> If you find a useful question on one of the Stack Exchange network sites (for example on Stack Overflow in English), which has not already been published on Stack Overflow in Spanish and the question is valid as described in *What topics can I ask here?*, please, translate the question and answer(s) into Spanish and post it on the site. Our manifesto:
>
> > Create a world where, for any search engine query, the search results show the link to a detailed answer in Spanish.
>
> The translations increase the knowledge available in Spanish and help thousands of colleagues to understand and solve problems currently limited by language barriers.
>
> ### What should I keep in mind when translating?
>
> *The author of the translations receives reputation*. Translated questions are equivalent to the answers in own questions . Please use this system to contribute to the knowledge in Spanish on the site.
>
> *Don't forget to cite the source and the original post*. Thank the original author of the posts by adding a link to their post in the translation.
>
> *Consider your field of knowledge*. The best thing would be to translate those questions that you already have subject matter expertise. In this case, your translations will contain vocabulary specific to the field covered and will help when translating future answers, suggested edits and comments.
>
> *Quality over quantity*. Poor quality translations, such as automatic translations, like any other publication can be closed and removed by the community. [**But as with this post, an automated translation may make a good first draft**]
>
> *Improvise*. When translating, you can merge several answers into one and thus create a canonical answer.